# Getting errors when I update to .NET 8.0

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core-mvc, maui, .net-8.0

After I updated to .NET 8.0, I encountered an error when creating a new project or reopening an old one. I will list the errors after when using the Visual Studio template.

Template: ASP.NET web application + Winforms

Error:

> NETSDK1004 assets file 'obj project.assets.json' not found, run a NuGet package restore to generate this file.

Template: .NET MAUI app

Error:

> XA1018 specified androidmanifest file does not exist

For ASP.NET web application + Winforms: I had tried to run NuGet package, but access denied to folder in D drive (then tried to run as Administrator and change D drive permission to full control but not work)

For .NET MAUI app: I had tried to Clean and Rebuild

Comment: You can try to delete the obj folders and bin folders, then rebuild it. If it still doesn’t work, try to restart the VS.

Comment: I bumped into this problem. . . but it was a friday. Switched the computer off and came back on the Monday to fix. . . but it works fine.

Hopefully you've had the same experience since posting.